# objective c - array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

**Grade.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Grade : NSObject
{
    int i;
    int score[5];
    int sum;    
}

-(void)setScore:(int)sc;
-(void)setSum:(int)su;

- (float)gradeAverage;
@end
```

**Grade.m**

```
#import "Grade.h"

@implementation Grade

- (void)setScore:(int)sc
{
    score[i]=sc;
}
- (void)setSum:(int)su
{
    sum=sum+score[i];
}

- (float)gradeAverage
{
    return sum/2.0;
}
@end
```

**main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Grade.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    Grade *person =[[Grade alloc]init];

    [person setScore:80];
    [person setScore:90];


    float ga =[person gradeAverage];
    NSLog(@"person %f",ga);
}
return 0;
}
```

The program received an average score tries to create the output.

```
(ex.input[1]:90(input value),input[2]:95(input value)->average=92.5)
```

the score is set to the array takes multiple values ​​will be averaged out.

However, creating and running the code in `main.m` it but was not running properly.

In addition to these `main.m` in different parts of it in the wrong part of my skills, but it is hard to fix this yet.

I hope your help. Thanks.

Comment: *objective c - array* is not really a question.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your small program](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: When is called `setSum`?

Comment: You should not be learning to program using Objective-C.  Use Java or plain C first.

Comment: To appreciate the various comment.

Answer (score 2):

The first error I see is that you use `i` without initializing or changing it, so it is always zero.  So you always store the score in the 0th slot of the array.

Furthermore, consider using `NSMutableArray` instead of a standard C array.  You may find it to be more friendly.  If you're bothering to use ObjectiveC, you may as well embrace its data structures.